# Chrome console outputs all show fs.js as source of log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome

Recently I noticed the outputs from console.log, info, etc were appearing in the chrome console as coming from fs.js while before it would show the source file + line number.

I'm trying to diagnose what caused this change - nothing has changed as far as I'm aware.

I'm in a NextJS react/typescript web app.

Early on in execution it does show the line number which makes me think something is being initialised that then sends things through fs.js.

Ultimately I just want to know the file source of any logging being output to chrome and an easy way to click through from chrome to see it in the chrome source viewer.

Comment: depends on what "fs.js" is - you haven't mentioned

Comment: Show code and console output and describe how expected result differs from the current one